# Remove zeros in pandas dataframe without effecting the imputation result

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, knn, imputation

I have a `timeseries dataset` with `5M rows`.

The column has `19.5% missing values`, `80% zeroes` (don't go by the percentage values - although it means only 0.5% of data is useful but then 0.5% of 5M is enough). Now, I need to impute this column.

Given the number of rows, it's **taking around 2.5 hours** for KNN to impute the whole thing.

To make it faster, I thought of deleting all the zero values rows and then carry out the imputation process. But I feel that using KNN ***naively*** after this would lead to overestimation (since all the zero values are gone and keeping the number of neighbours fixed, the mean is expected to increase).

So, is there a way:

- To modify the data input to the KNN model
- Carry out the imputation process after removing the rows with zeros so that the values obtained after imputation are the same or at least near

To understand the problem more clearly, consider the following dummy dataframe:

```py
    DATE    VALUE
0   2018-01-01  0.0
1   2018-01-02  8.0
2   2018-01-03  0.0
3   2018-01-04  0.0
4   2018-01-05  0.0
5   2018-01-06  10.0
6   2018-01-07  NaN
7   2018-01-08  9.0
8   2018-01-09  0.0
9   2018-01-10  0.0
```

Now, if I use `KNN (k=3)`, then with zeros, the value would be the weighted mean of `0`, `10` and `9`. But if I remove the zeros ***naively***, the value will be imputed with the weighted mean of `8`, `10` and `9`.

A few rough ideas which I thought of but could not proceed through were as follows:

1. Modifying the weights (used in the weighted mean computation) of the KNN imputation process so that the removed 0s are taken into account during the imputation.
2. Adding a column which says how many neighbouring zeros a particular column has and then somehow use it to modify the imputation process.

Points `1.` and `2.` are just rough ideas which came across my mind while thinking about how to solve the problem and might help one while answering the answer.

PS -

1. Obviously, I am not feeding the time series data directly into KNN. What I am doing is extracting `month`, `day`, etc. from the date column, and then using this for imputation.
2. I *do not need parallel processing as an answer* to make the code run faster. The data is so large that high RAM usage hangs my laptop.

Comment: Hi, @paradoxlover . Imputing with mean with zero in the data will affect your imputation significantly As the number of zero's is high and they are not having significance but they will act as outliers for sure while imputing the data. So, I would suggest using the median for your imputation as it is less bais towards outliers. You can refer to the following link why I am suggesting median as filler value. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143700/which-is-better-replacement-by-mean-and-replacement-by-median

Comment: Also, you can use the time series itself to find the missing values

Answer (score 0):

Let's think logically, leave the machine learning part aside for the moment.
Since we are dealing with time series, it would be good if you impute the data with the average of values for the same date in different years, say 2-3 years ( if we consider 2 years, then 1 year before and 1 year after the missing value year), would recommend not to go beyond 3 years. We have computed x now.
Further to make this computed value x close to the current data, use an average of x and y, y is linear interpolation value.
In the above example, y = (10 + 9)/2, i.e. average of one value before and one value after the data to be imputed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, unfortunately, the data is available for 6 months only.

Comment: Ok, then it is not feasible to use time series techniques here, what trend and seasonality you see in the data?

Comment: The time span is not considerably large to find any reasonable trend or seasonality!!!

Comment: But that's something I am not worried about. What I am really worried about is the large number of zeroes present in the dataset. It's kind of redundant and space consuming.

Comment: correct, that is what I want to say, data is insufficient to do a time series forecasting.